# Using JavaScript to get the text of an element using Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm doing automated testing using Laravel Dusk, when I do this:

```
$test = $browser->script('$(".page-sidebar-menu").text();');
dd($test);
```

It returns array of null, but if run `$(".page-sidebar-menu").text();` in a browser, it returns all text inside that class.

Where I go wrong in here? Please help if you know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay it's wrong of me to asked this, I not include return inside script
it should be like this

`$test = $browser->script('return $(".page-sidebar-menu").text();');
dd($test);`